# why getSideOutput emit nothing?

Tags: apache-flink

I using `getSideOutput` to create a side output stream, Presence of element in the pre-processing stream before processing with getSideOutput, but when calling `getSideOutput` method, nothing element is emitted.

code as follow

```
DataStream<String> asyncTable =
        join3
            .flatMap(new ExtractList())
            .process( // detect code using for test
                new ProcessFunction<String, String>() {
                  @Override
                  public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out)
                      throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(value); // can detect elements
                  }
                })
            .getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("asyTab", TypeInformation.of(String.class)));
```

but when calling `getSideOutput` method after

```
DataStream<String> asyncTable =
    join3
        .flatMap(new ExtractList())
        .getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("asyTab", TypeInformation.of(String.class)))
        .process(
            new ProcessFunction<String, String>() {
              @Override
              public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out)
                  throws Exception {
                System.out.println(value); // nothing  detect elements
              }
            });
```

`ExtractList` as follows

```
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;


public class ExtractList extends RichFlatMapFunction<NewTableA, String> {

  @Override
  public void flatMap(NewTableA value, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

    String tableName = "NewTableA";
    String primaryKeyName = "PA1";
    String primaryValue = value.getPA1().toString();

    String result = tableName+":"+primaryKeyName+":"+primaryValue;
    //System.out.println(result);  // right result output
    out.collect(result);
  }
}
```

why `getSideOutput` to create a side output stream with nothing elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same output tag id should be used - in your case, it's `asyncTableValue` in `ExtractList` and `asyTab` in `.getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("asyTab", TypeInformation.of(String.class)));` which are definetely different and therefore `asyTab` side output emits nothing.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it is my mistake.
I don't code in `ExtractList`

```
public class ExtractList extends ProcessFunction<NewTableA, NewTableA> {
  private OutputTag<String> asyncTableValue =
      new OutputTag<String>("asyncTableValue", TypeInformation.of(String.class));

  @Override
  public void processElement(NewTableA value, Context ctx, Collector<NewTableA> out)
      throws Exception {
    String tableName = "NewTableA";
    String primaryKeyName = "PA1";
    String primaryValue = value.getPA1().toString();

    String result = tableName + ":" + primaryKeyName + ":" + primaryValue;

    ctx.output(asyncTableValue, result);

    out.collect(value);
  }
}
```